# Include extra files in jar

Tags: ros, rosjava, gradle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read from xml and gram files in my Java node

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("config.xml");
    configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager(url);
```

However, this xml file is not included in the jar file created by the gradle. That's why my app will keep returning NullPointerException.

I tried adding files as dependency to build.gradle file, without succes

runtime fileTree(dir: 'src/path/to/my/class', include: ['*.gram'])
runtime fileTree(dir: 'src/path/to/my/class', include: ['*.xml'])

I read at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410828/gradle-add-single-file-to-jar) , that i should add from "rule" to the jar task, but I can't find it.

So, how can I add files to the jar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213161/include-extra-files-in-jar/) by [smihael](https://answers.ros.org/users/23102/smihael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24726945/822644

---

Originally posted by [smihael](https://answers.ros.org/users/23102/smihael/) with karma: 45 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0